# Regular expression Alphanumeric and symbols [-*/]

Tags: c++, regex

I have he following regular expression : `(?!^[0-9]*$)(?!^[a-zA-Z]*$)^([a-zA-Z0-9]{3,30})$`
I use it to extract the alphanumeric patterns : ITC766, HELLO07 etc.

I am not so familiar with regular expressions. How can I modify to be able to extract alphanumeric patterns with special symbols?

**For example :** ITC-766, ITC/766, 766-ITC, Hello-86234...

Special characters like :

```
"-","_", ".", ",",";"
```

Thank you,
Hani.

Comment: Can you show some of your related code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add those characters into the character class, making it `[-_.,;a-zA-Z0-9]`, so the full regex is:

`(?!^[0-9]*$)(?!^[a-zA-Z]*$)^([-_.,;a-zA-Z0-9]{3,30})$`

Note that it's important that the `-` is the first character in the class, otherwise it has the special meaning used in `a-z`.